# Pygame/Tkinter duplicate window when importing

Tags: python

I have two files, window.py and game.py. Window.py contains all the code for the window, and interfaces with game.py.

When I run window.py, it imports game.py directly at the start. However, in game.py, it only imports game.py when it needs it, inside functions. However, this means than whenever it imports game.py, it makes a new blank Tkinter window. The code is similar to this:

TEST.py

```
from tkinter import *
import test2

txt = 'txt'

root = Tk()
root.wm_title("TEST")

e=Entry(root)
e.pack()

def func(event):
    global txt
    txt = e.get()
    test2.fun()

root.bind('<Return>', func)   

test2.start()

while True:
    root.update()
```

TEST2.py

```
def start():
    import test
    print('You have entered:')

def fun():
    import test
    print(test.txt)
```

This gives two windows, where one seems to be a 'lesser' copy of the other, not having all the features of it. Unfortunately, I do not know to shoehorn an `if __name__ = '__main__'` type argument. My actual code is here:

https://github.com/Deonyi/CF/blob/master/windows.pyw

with the Tkinter code starting at Line 173.

Comment: You should rethink your logic a little. There shouldn't be any need for circular imports, why do you need this?

Comment: Why do you import `test` in your `test2.py` module?

Comment: I import it so that test2.py can get a variable from test.py. Or rather, in the case of my actual code, so that it can replicate the function of the `input()` method in a GUI with a Tkinter entry. I probably could move the logic into test.py, but that would greatly complicate things. Is there a way I could do this with circular imports?